# Estimating integer integrals based on other definite integrals

Tags: linear-algebra, definite-integrals, data-analysis

I'm working with a continous dataset that is incomplete and my task is to find the most likely values assuing normal distribution of all data.

I'm given a series of integrals such that $\int^5_{0}f(x)dx = 3$, $\int^7_{25}f(x)dx=20$, $\int^{20}_{30}f(x)dx=8$

Now I'm looking for either mathematical or programmating ways to estimate what is the most likely value of each single integer integral in the dataset, so that: $y_n=\int_{n}^{n+1} f(x) dx$

I'd appreciate any good starting points or recommendations.

Comment: Are the limits on your integrals correct? (Some go from lower to higher values, others the other way round) And are those all the values you have, or just a sample? If you define $y_n=\int_{n}^{n+1} f(x) dx$ your notation gets a lot simpler

Comment: Great point, edited the notation!

This is the sample of values; Generally for each data-set there will be up to 20 integrals. However, the method should work with as few as 3.

Comment: The reason I suggested that notation was that the information you're given is in that form. In the question as it's worded now, you're saying $\sum_{n=0}^4 y_n = 3$, $\sum_{n=7}^{24} y_n = -20$ and $\sum_{n=20}^{29} y_n = -8$. I'm finding the negative totals confusing if you also mean that $f(x)$ should fit a Gaussian curve - that's why I asked about the limits